# Ubuntu server 18.04 apache2 how to change the default page?

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2

I will keep this short. I am trying to figure out how to change the default page for apache2 to point at my oscommerce site instead by default. I have deleted the default index.html file.

As of now I have to type:
https://myIPaddress/oscommerce/catalog

My default install location for oscommerce is:
/var/www/html/oscommerce/

What I want to type to get to the oscommerce site:
https://myIPaddress

I have created a oscommerce.conf file but I am unsure how to get apache2 to point to the site. Sorry if I am missing information. I am new to linux and I will give more information as needed.
This is what I am running into at this time
[Index /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUbSs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change document root of apache2

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf |grep DocumentRoot
leonid@DevSSD:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf |grep DocumentRoot
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Above commands not find documentroot in main config, but find it in default virtualhost config, run commands and find out where this setting located. Edit file by `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
Change DocumentRoot to your site folder /var/www/html/oscommerce/, then restart apache2 by `systemctl reload apache2`

Update: Apache gives permission error in two cases, first when file permissions not allowing apache2 to read folder/file, when folder requested, e.g. / at end of request line but no index file found.
To fix file/folder permissions:

```
sudo chown -R youruser:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /var/www
```

Additionaly, if web application writes something to some folder, like templates_cache, give that folder write permissions for group.

For index type of error look for DirectoryIndex option in config files

Edited by User asking the question.
The way I fixed this issue is by changing the DocumentRoot for my site config and also creating a index.html file to redirect from the DocumentRoot to the site
Index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; URL='https://myIPaddress/oscommerce/catalog/index.php'" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there index.html or index.php or some other index in /var/www/html/oscommerce/?

Comment: Are https://myipaddress/catalog working? Do you have some site files outside `catalog`? What files are in /var/www/html/oscommerce/ ? You may point documentroot to /var/www/html/oscommerce/catalog but I don't know if it correct, as don't know your app structure.

Comment: its wrong - /var/www/html/oscommerce/catalog/index.php. It should be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/oscommerce/catalog/` without file name. Don't forget to restart apache after change

Comment: What I see, you have changed DocumentRoot not correctly, may be not in all places of config. You should not see oscommerse as DocumentRoot should point above it.

Comment: You may also do redirect by index.php file, with the following content: `<?php header('Location: https://myIPaddress/oscommerce/catalog/index.php');`